# what is difference between view and task in joomla 2.5 and what is url structure in joomla 2.5?

Tags: php, joomla

I'm new to joomla2.5 and i'm working on a form component that will simple get data from user and save to database but i have confusion regarding form redirect.

please tell me what means of this:

index.php?option=com_users&task=registration.register

please define me "task=registration.register" including dot also.

index.php?option=com_test2&view=test2

please define different between view and task and what is joomla2.5 url structure fundamentals.

Thanks with regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Joomla,

View stands for component views.
A component have multiple views like Joomla default component com_users have different views

```
registration,profile etc
```

Task means the function inside your controller file.

like here

index.php?option=com_users&task=registration.register

`registration` controller have a function name with `register`

In the view

index.php?option=com_test2&view=test2

means component `com_test2` have a view folder with `test2`

In other way you can access the `register` function inside your controller is by using hidden fields. If you have a form to submit then something like.

```
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_users"/>
<input type="hidden" name="controller" value="registration"/>
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="register"/>
```

You will get more details about Joomla component structure from [here](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component/Introduction)

Hope its helps..