# how to get database value from ajax in joomla module?

Tags: jquery, ajax, joomla

I am creating a module where i want to get database value from ajax.
anybody have a solution of this problem or any example please help me...
can anyone give me a proper way for this.......

this is my `jquery` code-

```
jQuery('.type').bind('click', function() {
      var feedId = jQuery(this).attr('id');
      alert(feedId);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "modules/mod_feedback/ajax.php",
        data: {"Type":feedId},
        success: function(reviews){
            //jQuery(".show").html(response);
            alert(reviews);
        }
    });
  });
```

and this is my `ajax.php` code-

```
require_once( 'helper.php' ); 
$reviews = modfeedbackHelper::getFeedbackResultIdea();
echo $reviews;
```

Comment: no i am not getting any error but in alert(reviews) it show nothing.the same function  modfeedbackHelper::getFeedbackResultIdea(); when use in default.php  it work properly but in ajax page it not work.

Comment: What Joomla version are you using? Joomla 3.2 have com_ajax for module ajax calls, in other case you need to create a component for ajax calls. You can't use ajax calls in the module.

Comment: i am using joomla 3.2

Comment: No issues which version of joomla you are using you can make ajax calls from anywhere without the help of component..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ajax Call.

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "//PATH of ajax.php",
            data: { //Data to pass},
            cache: false,
                success: function(html)
                {
                    //DO SOMETHING  
                }
            });
```

and in ajax.php

```
 require_once( 'helper.php' );

 $reviews = modfeedbackHelper::getFeedbackResultIdea();

 echo $reviews; exit;
```

That should do :):)

Comment: Have you returned something from getFeedbackResultIdea() function ??

Comment: this function working in default.php page but in ajax page i am not sure about this.how to check that it will return somthing or not??

Comment: what is the path of ajax page??

Comment: path of ajax page-url: "modules/mod_feedback/ajax.php",

Comment: use <?php echo JURI::root() ;?> in ajax call to ajax.php.      $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "<?php echo JURI::root() ;?>like.php",

Comment: @amit Its wrong ! Joomla do not supports ajax call to module or plugins it required components or external files.In joomla standard you should use component for this type of requirements.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you're trying to make an ajax call to the files inside module and its not a part of the module, so it act like external php file

`modules/mod_feedback/ajax.php` is wrong. You have to make the ajax call to the related component controller like below.

```
jQuery('.type').bind('click', function() {
      var feedId = jQuery(this).attr('id');
      alert(feedId);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php?option=com_yourcomponent&task=yourcontroller.your_function",
        data: {"Type":feedId},
        success: function(reviews){
            //jQuery(".show").html(response);
            alert(reviews);
        }
    });
  });
```

Then inside your controller file a function named with `your_function`

and have the following codes inside your function

```
require_once( JPATH_SITE.'/modules/mod_feedback/helper.php' );

 $reviews = modfeedbackHelper::getFeedbackResultIdea();

 echo $reviews; exit;
```

Then it will work otherwise you have to load Joomla frame work to your ajax.php its a bad idea. try to follow correct methods.

Hope its helps..

Comment: what is the index.php file?

Comment: Joomla all files render through index.php if you are trying to access any functions inside controller via url should use above format otherwise you can use hidden fields . try using com_ajax if no related component for this module.