# Jinput not working for joomla

Tags: post, input, joomla, get, jinput

I've been stuck on this problem with no clue as to why this doesn't work.

I'm using Joomla 2.5 and building my own component.

I have a 'Books' and 'Book' view. 'Books' lists all the books from the database and 'Book' is where I add/edit my book item. I'm trying to pass a value from 'Books' to 'Book' but it doesn't work.

I've set up an input text with a value to pass on.

```
<input type="text" id="test" name="test" value="testvalue" />
```

views/books/tmpl/default.php

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_test'); ?>" method="post" name="adminForm">
        <table class="adminlist">
                <thead><?php echo $this->loadTemplate('head');?></thead>
                <tfoot><?php echo $this->loadTemplate('foot');?></tfoot>
                <tbody><?php echo $this->loadTemplate('body');?></tbody>
        </table>
        <div>
                <input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" name="boxchecked" value="0" />
                <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>

                <!-- For sorting -->
                <input type="hidden" name="filter_order" value="<?php echo $this->sortColumn; ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="filter_order_Dir" value="<?php echo $this->sortDirection; ?>" />
                <input type="text" id="test" name="test" value="testvalue" />
        </div>
</form>
```

And in my book view.html.php file views/book/view.html.php

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
echo  'value:'.$jinput->get('test');
```

There will be no value. I've tried $_POST('test') but it still doesn't work. Can anyone please point me at the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The Post data should be received in `Controller`  not in `view`.

Once you submit the form it should have controller and model to handle the `POST` data.

check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029807/what-is-difference-between-view-and-task-in-joomla-2-5-and-what-is-url-structure/19032535#19032535) and understand the work flow, then on your controller you can try the same code it will works.

Joomla [MVC component structure](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_a_view_to_the_site_part)

Hope its helps..